# Do we have a way to train model in seq by the list of model names in python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I was reading an article but I couldn't find it now.

Do you have any clue to train model using its name as parameters?

something like:

```
model_level1 = ['svm','decision_tree','logistic_regression']
model_level2 = ['random_forest','neural_network']
```

and training as a pipeline, which is using the result of the first level as the input of the second level's models.

But I don't remember the exact code to do that and I can't find the result online, I really remember I read someone doing it that way and it is elegant.

Answer (score 0):

After several days research, I think there is one candidate for process in pipeline:

We could use Pipeline from sklearn.pipeline to do some jobs

```
>>> from sklearn.svm import SVC
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
>>> from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
>>> from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
>>> X, y = make_classification(random_state=0)
>>> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
...                                                     random_state=0)
>>> pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('svc', SVC())])
>>> # The pipeline can be used as any other estimator
>>> # and avoids leaking the test set into the train set
>>> pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('svc', SVC())])
>>> pipe.score(X_test, y_test)
```